# devise_token_auth automatic sign_in after sign_up, returning sign_in.json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

**Using:**

- Rails 5
- devise_auth_token

**Site Info:**

- Site used strictly for apis
- Apis will be consumed by mobile apps; sign up, sign in, other CRUD operations, etc.
- All apis will return json

**What I want to do:**

I want to be able to automatically sign_in a user ***after they have successfully sign[ed]_up*** AND return the header and json normally returned from DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create.json - so the auth token, client, uid, etc. can be used in subsequent api calls. I haven't overridden DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController, but I can if I need to. BTW, although I want to sign_in the user after a successful sign_up, I don't want to disable the confirmation email normally sent after sign_up; I do want the user to have to confirm the email address entered.

Also, any additional advice/gotchas/etc. you can add in addition to your answer would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: API's should be stateless, meaning sessions aren't tracked. You should use another form of authenticating API requests such as OAuth or API Keys depending on the level of security you need.

Comment: @meshpi I've turned session off, and I just found out I need to remove the session routes in routes.rb as well, meaning they're not used; I guess my question becomes: what does the authentication process actually look like after sign up. The only route left besides password and registration routes is validate_token.